# Tabs and Fragments exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I want to implement the idea that my every tab would have a separate activity. Here is the code where i am create tabs:

```
public class MainTabActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab_activity);

        try {
            TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

            mTabHost.setup();

            Resources res = getResources();

            TabHost.TabSpec spec;
            Intent intent;

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, stackA.class);

            spec = mTabHost
                    .newTabSpec("tab1")
                    .setIndicator("Tab 1",
                            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContent(intent);
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, stackB.class);

            spec = mTabHost
                    .newTabSpec("tab2")
                    .setIndicator("Tab 2",
                            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                    .setContent(intent);
            mTabHost.addTab(spec);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }




}
```

I am getting an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
```

So maybe someone know solution if i want to extened FragmentsActivity as TabActivity is depricated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend `ActivityGroup` instead of `Activity` and instead of `mTabHost.setup()` use `mTabHost.setup(getLocalActivityManager());`

Comment: But ActivityGroup is depricated from android 3.*. So is there other way ?

Comment: Use Fragment, as the documentation recommends when it says ActivityGroup is deprecated.

Comment: Indeed they are, I am just used to the old ways I guess :D haven't tried the fragment API might give it a spin today and let you know.

Comment: I can't do functionality with fragments as i want. that i could go tab1-->view1-->view2 and go back with back button

Comment: I really don't know, but I think you can get away for now by doing it using ActivityGroup if time is of the essence to you.